# Why does putting a pointer in an interface{} in Go cause reflect to lose the name of the type?

Tags: pointers, reflection, go

The example below shows what happens when you reflect on an interface {} that is set to an object (g) and a pointer to said object (h). Is this by design, should I expect that my datatype is lost or rather or that I cannot get name of the datatype back when I put my pointer in an interface {}?

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type Foo struct {
    Bar string
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{Bar: "FooBar"}
    typeName := reflect.TypeOf(f).Name()
    fmt.Printf("typeName %v\n", typeName)

    var g interface{}
    g = f
    typeName = reflect.TypeOf(g).Name()
    fmt.Printf("typeName %v\n", typeName)

    var h interface{}
    h = &f
    typeName = reflect.TypeOf(h).Name()
    fmt.Printf("typeName %v\n", typeName)
}
```

Outputs:

```
typeName Foo
typeName Foo
typeName
```

Also at:

http://play.golang.org/p/2QuBoDxHfX

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the `Name` method's documentation says, unnamed types will return an empty string:

> `Name` returns the type's name within its package.
>   It returns an empty string for unnamed types.

The type of `h` is an unnamed pointer type whose element type is the named struct type `Foo`:

```
v := reflect.TypeOf(h)
fmt.Println(v.Elem().Name()) // prints "Foo"
```

If you want an identifier for complex unnamed types like this, use the `String` method:

```
fmt.Println(v.String()) // prints "*main.Foo"
```

Comment: Thanks!. Really interesting. Reading the docs on Elem() is a bit confusing.         // Elem returns a type's element type.
// It panics if the type's Kind is not Array, Chan, Map, Ptr, or Slice.
Elem() Type. So, reflect.TypeOf returned a Type, Elem returns an elements Type. Is the "element" the value that I'm reflecting on?

Comment: Also, it seems that the only reason Elem() isn't panic'ing is because the contained type is a pointer. I find it interesting that Elem().Name() then returns "Foo" instead of *Foo.

Comment: @Nate: The name `Elem` is a bit missleading for pointers but it is perfectly sensible for the other types. E.g. if you reflect on a `[]int` the `Elem()` method gives you the type of the slice elements, here int (and not []int). The same logic applies to pointers:You reflect on a pointer type and `Elem()` gives you the type of the "element of the pointer type" and thats Name is clearly "Foo" not "*Foo" as the name of the element of a []int is int and not []int.

Comment: For what it is worth, the type of `h` is `interface{}` not a pointer type. It is the *value* of `h` that has (unnamed) pointer type. This becomes apparent if you pass in `&h` to `reflect.TypeOf` instead of `h`. However, interfaces are passed by value (mostly) in Go, and `reflect.TypeOf` takes `interface{}` so it has no way of knowing the type of `h` if passed by value. This distinction is not super important here, but would be more noticeable if `h` had a named interface type like `io.Reader`.